# How to call JavaScript method while click on p:calendar .ui-datepicker-month(select)?

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am developing a project with `Primefaces`.

In my project, I need to call the `JavaScript` method when select the month from the `p:calendar`.

I have tried with some scenario but no use.

**Sample Code:**

```
      $(document).on('change', '.ui-datepicker-title .ui-datepicker-month', function() {
            changeMonth();
       });

      $(document).on('click', '.ui-datepicker-trigger', function() {
            changeMonth();
       });


      function changeMonth()
        {
            alert("Called");
        }
```

The `.ui-datepicker-title` `.ui-datepicker-month and .ui-datepicker-trigger` are the default `p:calendar` classes.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Are you trying to call a function when the month is changed?

Comment: @Arun P Johny Yeah, Yes

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the Primefaces Userguide

> Another handy event is the viewChange that is fired when month and year changes. An instance of
>   org.primefaces.event.DateViewChangeEvent is passed to the event listener providing the current
>   month and year information.

So give it a try

```
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date}">
    <p:ajax event="viewChange" oncomplete="changeMonth()" />
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: Thanx lot. its works fine and plz see my updated question. I need to call that same JavaScript method when click on p:calendar button.

Comment: you mean the event if you click at an specific date?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:column headerText="Validity From " >  <p:calendar  id="faFromDate"  p:placeholder="DD-MM-YY"    value="#{item.fAFromDate}" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Please enter validity from date." 
  pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" >
   <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{agronomistPageBean2.ajaxListener()}" update="faToDate" /> 
  </p:calendar>

  </p:column>
```

**This will  100% call ajax method.**